# Nodeschool's Stream-Adventure #12 Duplexer redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

It's been days since I'm trying several ways to solve this exercice. I give up. What am I doing wrong here ? Why am I getting "write after end" error if the event I'm using is the "end" event and I don't write anything to the pipe ? I'm just changing an object after it's use. Or at least I think so.

```
var duplexer2 = require("duplexer2");
var through = require('through2');


module.exports = function (counter) {
    var countries = {};        

    var duplex = duplexer2(through.obj(function (obj, encoding, done) {
        if (obj.country in countries)
            countries[obj.country]++;
        else 
            countries[obj.country] = 1;  
        done();
    }), counter);

    duplex.on("finish", function() {
        counter.setCounts(countries);
    });

    counter.pipe(duplex);

    return duplex;
};
```

If I substitute the line `counter.setCounts(countries);` for `console.log(countries)` I see that it's populated correctly.

Problem text: http://pastebin.com/vAM4vKZg

I have read this exercice test file and counldn't get any clue from it as it only compares the objects to see if they're correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct. Just remove the `counter.pipe(duplex);` line and it works. You do not need to pipe anything to the duplex stream you created, the stream adventure is going to do that to check if it works :).

Comment: Oh my god... several days trying to solve it and this was the only line I haven't changed. :D Silly me